# My log file size is 121 GB how to reduce?

Tags: logging, database, transaction-log, navision

We are using Navision 2009 and the database transaction log file has grown to 121GB. We would like to shrink the file. Can this be done?

Comment: Do you take backups of the database?

Answer (score 7):

Do a full backup with truncate logs. You should be backing up the database on a regular basis.

Contact your MS Partner and they'll know how to fix it too. If you don't have an assigned MS Partner, you should find one in your area. (Full Disclosure: I work for a MS Dynamics Partner).

Comment: To add to Chris' answer we used to run AX and the DB/Logs would get large.  We used Microsoft's DPM product and it does a decent job at cleaning up the log file with every backup.